# ffmpeg - multiple watermarks with fade effects

Tags: ffmpeg

Only the second watermark is present when using this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -loop 1 -i wm1.png -loop 1 -i wm2.png -c:a copy 
-filter_complex "[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=30:d=0.5[watermark1];
[0:v][watermark1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1[video1];
[2:v]fade=in:st=30:d=0.5,fade=out:st=60:d=0.5[watermark2];
[video1][watermark2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1" out.mp4
```

Comment: Please add the full, uncut command line output, and ideally, also a sample image/video to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `alpha=1` to the `fade` filters.